# Method Overloading null parameter

Tags: java, operator-overloading

In my code, I have a method which has got to take 4 parameters. But in somewhere in the code i call this method with sometimes 2, sometimes 4 parameters. So when i call with 2 parameters, the last 2 parameters should go automaticly null.

For example:

```
public static void x(String one,String two,String three=null,String four=null){

//do something hear

}

x("one","two");
x("one","two","three","four");
```

When I call x("one","two") => I want that the three and four parameters automatticaly initialize to null.

How can i do that ? Thanks for helps.

Comment: `Method Overloading` is your friend.

Comment: Java doesn't support default parameters :(

Comment: @MarounMaroun they do not support default parameters but support infinite parameters `do(String... strings)`

Comment: Thanks for showing the infinite parameters.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A{

   public void do(String a, String b, String c, String d){
        //do something
   }

   //Overload do method
   public void do(String a, String b){
        do(a,b,null,null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks like useful but i forgot to say that,  in the code there are lots of calls for with 2 parameters. So i cannot change hole code. I need an answer with default parameters :/

Comment: @BatuhanBardak Yes, you can create a four parameters method, copy the whole code into it, and then use the 2 parameteres method to call the 4 one.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to keep your method with 4 parameters only, just when you need to pass only 2 parameters, pass the other 2 parameters as null.

For Example for 2 params pass:

```
    x(a,b,null,null);
```

and for 4 params pass:

```
    x(a,b,c,d);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as well and can be called using an Array of Strings as parameter, or multiple comma separated Strings. This way you don't have to overload.

```
public void myMethod(String ...strings)  {
    for (String string : strings) {
        //do something with the string
    }
}
```

you can call it using an array:

```
myMethod(new String[]{"test1", "test2"})
```

or several Strings:

```
myMethod("test1", "test2");
myMethod("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4");
```